# Auto assignment of the C# application version in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, version, auto-increment

I've tried a lot of different options: 1) changed the versions in the solution properties via Visual Studio 2) edited the file.csproj 3) created applications .Net Framework 4.8 and .NET 6 / 7 4) Used the * sign 5) specified versions in the formats 1.2.* and 1.2.0.* 6) used the false value of the Deterministic property and generally tried different solutions found on SO. But no matter what I do, when viewing the version of my application in file Explorer, 0 is always substituted instead of an asterisk and this does not change in any way, no matter how much I recompile the program, making changes to it. At the same time, many years ago I was able to create auto-incrementing versions of applications.NetFramework in the SharpDevelop IDE and I imagine that the result should not be the same as it is now.

Please help me understand the reason why the file version always remains unchanged and zero is always substituted instead of wildcard.